# Facebook-API- Inviting members to group method returns 'Unknown method' error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

API reference to method :https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/group/members

Endpoint : https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2//members

I am making an api call in facebook to invite members to a group. I am using the above shown endpoint and sending 'member' parameter with a userId value. But the response was

{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#3) Unknown method", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 3
  }
}

I am sending a correct Access Token with all the necessary privileges but I couldn't get it solved. Can someone please guide me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Apps can invite people (if they are an admin, developer, or tester of the app) to a group created by that app

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/group/members/

Meaning, it´s not possible to invite users to any group, only to App groups.

Also, you are missing something in your endpoint:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2//members
```

...i guess you mean:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/group-id/members
```

Comment: So, isn't it possible to invite members to a normal group through the facebook API? Why I raised this question is it was possible with the unversioned facebok API and apparently the function invocation is not anymore supported through the current API.

Comment: i believe it was possible earlier with v1.0, but it is definitely not possibly anymore in new apps.

Answer (score 0):

User being invited must be a user of the application. Also, users can only be invited once. Subsequent invites will fail.